# Problem while inserting float

Tags: floats, lyx

I am using LyX Version 2.3.4.2 (Friday, February 7, 2020), pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019/Debian) in Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS.

I was using Lyx and it was running fine for quite few weeks.

Suddenly, I got this error. While inserting a float, Figure caption is showing **UNDEFINED**. In pdf output, **Figure** is not coming. I am attaching screenshots.
[image]

```
%% LyX 2.3.4.2 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.

\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
This is an error I am facing.
\begin{figure}
\begin{centering}
\includegraphics{wan}
\par\end{centering}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It's hard to say without the code. Can you show us some of that? At least your document setup and the misbehaving figure?

Comment: Paste in the question the full source code (Latex code that show the Code Preview Pane, with "Complete source" selected) excepting the comment lines.

Comment: Ok, if that is the full code, I would guess the caption says "UNDEFINED" because you have not put in a caption. To get a caption, you have to put \caption{caption} after the \includegraphics{graphic} if you want it above, or after \includegraphics{graphic} if you want it below. (also, you will have problems if your graphic is not in the same directory as your document unless you specify the path).

Comment: (i) `centering` is not environment but switch in text formatting (see followed MWE), (ii) with demo image provided by `graphicx` package slightly corrected your MWE works fine: `\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{babel}

\begin{document}
This is an error I am facing.
\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\includegraphics{wan}
\caption{My beautiful figure \dots}
\end{figure}
\end{document}`

Comment: Well, it seems that LyX doesn't know what it's doing, because `\begin{centering}...\par\end{centering}` is hilarious. Just `\centering` at the start suffices and it's much better and easier syntax. Apparently, LyX balks because you didn't specify a caption; how to do it with LyX is beyond my knowledge. Another reason for avoiding it, in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks Plergux. Your suggestion has worked for latex. However, my problem for lyx is not solved.

Comment: You could remove the "centering" that LyX does and then insert in ERT the custom LaTeX you want. It would be great if you could open a ticket on trac at https://www.lyx.org/trac and post a minimal example .lyx file.

Comment: @egreg  Lyx does insert nothing except the empty caption in a new float (e.g.: `\begin{figure}\caption{}\end{figure}`) The rest is fault of the user. Moreover, at least in my version 2.3.4.2, "Paragraph settings" > "Center" in a normal text produces certainly      `\begin{centering} <selected contents> \par\end{centering}`  but inside a float the result is `\centering{} <selected contents>`, so maybe is a problem of outdated versions.

Comment: @Fran `\begin{centering}...\par\end{centering}` is wrong in any case. A centered paragraph *needs* vertical separation fore and aft as a general rule. For the rare case when it doesn't, one can decide to do differently.

Comment: I think: Lyx is not inserting the line \caption{}. That is why UNDEFINED is coming in Figure caption.